# Proving sum of fundamental basis*its transpose is Identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm introuble when I try to prove it.
$$v_1, v_2, ... , v_n$$ is orthonormal basis for $R^n$
Then I have to prove that $$v_1v_1^t+v_2v_2^t ... v_nv_n^t = I$$
Looks like I can solve it with
$$(v_1+v_2+ ... + v_n)(v_1+v_2+ ... + v_n)^t = v_1v_1^t+v_2v_2^t ... v_nv_n^t$$
But found no progress.

Comment: Please correct ur format!

Comment: Your proposed factorization doesn't work, unfortunately: If $i \neq j$, then $v_{i} v_{j}^{t}$ is the (non-zero) "outer" product of $v_{i}$ and $v_{j}$. (Try it with the standard basis if this isn't clear.) Instead, can you calculate the product of $\sum_{i} v_{i} v_{i}^{t}$ with an arbitrary ordered $n$-tuple $x$, perhaps using a formula you've seen recently?

Comment: I'm learning linear algebra these days, but I'm not sure what formula you mean.

Comment: @user325050: Every vector $x$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination $\sum_{i} x_{i} v_{i}$. Have you seen a formula for the coefficients $x_{i}$ under the assumption the $v_{i}$ form an orthonormal basis? (If not: What happens if you dot each side of the linear combination with a general basis element $v_{j}$?)